# Nuxt get Heading tag from API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to set OG:Tag from API

```
head() {
this.$axios
  .get(`............`)
  .then((response) => {
    this.og_title = response.data.message.course.course_name;
    this.og_description = response.data.message.course.description;
    this.og_image = response.data.message.course.img_url;

    console.log(this.og_title);
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        {
          property: "og:title",
          content: this.og_title,
        },
        {
          property: "og:description",
          content: this.og_description,
        },
        {
          property: "og:image",
          content: this.og_image,
        },
      ],
    };
  });
```

and it does not work But in console it already print correctly total but when test on production it does not have any tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform Axios request (and any other async calls) in **asyncData** method.
**asyncData** simply merges its return value into your component's local state, so you can access that data with *this*.

Please note, **asyncData** only works in *pages* folder components.

Here's an example using the @nuxt/http library:

```
<script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ params, $http }) {
      const post = await $http.$get(`https://api.nuxtjs.dev/posts/${params.id}`)
      return { post }
    },
    head() {
      return {
        title: this.post.title,
        meta: [
          {
            property: "og:title",
            content: this.post.title,
          },
          {
            property: "og:description",
            content: this.post.description,
          },
          {
            property: "og:image",
            content: this.post.image,
          },
        ],
      };
    }
  }
</script>
```